Filter Date Column by multiple criteria
I have a Date Column in Power BI that displays dates in the typical dd/mm/yyyy format.
I would like to display, on a bar chart, the following:

One bar that sums the # of people that have a date between 03/25/2024-10/24/2024
and another bar that sums the # of people who have a date on or after 10/24/2024


you can try this to create a column
Column=
IF (
    'Table'[Date] >= DATE ( 2024, 3, 25 )
        && 'Table'[Date] < DATE ( 2024, 10, 23 ),
    "bar1",
    IF ( 'Table'[Date] >= DATE ( 2024, 10, 24 ), "bar2" )
)

and not select blank in the filter

or you can use group and bin function, pls see the link below
enter link description here
